# SharePoint 2007 - Document library permissions per document

Tags: document-library, permissions

I want to change the permissions scheme of SharePoint 2007 Document Library, instead of configuring permission levels for the entire library, I want the ability to set the permissions per document inside the library.

Eg. one document library, many documents, each user (within the one group/audience) has unique view edit or delete permissions per each document.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, open the Document View and hover over the document. Click on the DropDown menu that appears and select "Manage Permissions".

You can then assign unique permissions to that document. (You will be asked if you want to "Stop inheriting permissions" Say OK to that, and the document will now have it's own permissions)

Keep in mind that all newly uploaded documents inherit permissions from the library, so you would have to do it for each new document - which can become tedious.

Two solutions to that:

- Create Folders in the Document Library and assign permissions to them
- If you have a Developer, ask him to write a [List Item Event Receiver](http://www.davehunter.co.uk/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=f0e16a1a-6fa9-4130-bcab-baeb97ccc4ff&ID=69)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this only works for the root admin, is there an option somewhere else I can select that will enable it for the other admins?

Comment: @Green it works for everyone that has "Manage Lists" permissions on the List. I think it's Hierarchy Manager or Design. Being a member of the **Sitename** Owner group should also help.